# how do I create a function for each onclick() input submit?

Tags: javascript, function, input, onclick, addeventlistener

I have tried to create a function for each input submit. The first input is for sum, the second for subtraction, third division and fourth multiplication. When I click on input (id="soma"), the console shows that soma() is not a function, but I alreasy created a function soma(); See the code below:

```js
const formHtml = document.querySelector('#form');
const campo1 = document.querySelector('#campo1');
const campo2 = document.querySelector('#campo2')
const resultado = document.querySelector('.resultado');
const num1 = Number(campo1.value);
const num2 = Number(campo2.value);

formHtml.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const soma = document.querySelector('#soma');
  soma.onclick() = function somar() {
    const somando = num1 + num2;
    resultado.innerHTML += `A soma foi ${somando}`;
  }
  const sub = document.querySelector('#sub');
  sub.onclick() = function sub() {
    const subtraindo = num1 - num2;
    resultado.innerHTML += `A subtração foi ${subtraindo}`;
  }
  const divi = document.querySelector('#divi');
  divi.onclick() = function divi() {
    const dividindo = num1 / num2;
    resultado.innerHTML += `A divisão foi ${dividindo}`;
  }
  const multip = document.querySelector('#multip');
  multip.onclick() = function multip() {
    const multiplicando = num1 * num2;
    resultado.innerHTML += `A multiplicação foi ${multiplicando}`;
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="number" name="campo1" id="campo1">
  <input type="number" name="campo2" id="campo2">
  <input type="submit" value="soma" id="soma" onclick="somar()">
  <input type="submit" value="subtração" id="sub" onclick="sub()">
  <input type="submit" value="divisão" id="divi" onclick="divi()">
  <input type="submit" value="multiplicação" id="multip" onclick="multip()">
  <div class="resultado">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your syntax isn't quite right. `soma.onclick() = function somar() {` Define your function(s) (`function somar() {...}` and then use assign them (`soma.addEventListener("click",somar)` or define the functions anonymously (`soma.addEventListener("click",function() {...});`

Comment: `const num1 = Number(campo1.value);
const num2 = Number(campo2.value);` is when the page runs, not when you click buttons.... So if you change the values, it is not going to get the updated values. Really unclear why you are binding event handlers inside of the submit event. What is the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

A very clever approach for this in order to keep the code as clean as possible is to assign an **id** to each **button** which matches the name of the function you want to use for that button.

Than we can easily use the appropriate function for each button click.

```js
const resultado = document.querySelector('.resultado');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[type=button]');

const mathFunctions = {
  soma: (num1, num2) => `A soma foi ${num1 + num2}`,
  sub: (num1, num2) => `A subtração foi ${num1 - num2}`,
  multip: (num1, num2) => `A multiplicação foi ${num1 * num2}`,
  divi: (num1, num2) => `A divisão foi ${num1 / num2}`
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const num1 = Number(document.querySelector('#campo1').value);
    const num2 = Number(document.querySelector('#campo2').value);

    const mathFunction = mathFunctions[button.id];
    const resultText = mathFunction(num1, num2);

    resultado.innerHtml = resultText;
  })
})
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="number" name="campo1" id="campo1">
  <input type="number" name="campo2" id="campo2">
  <input type="button" value="soma" id="soma">
  <input type="button" value="subtração" id="sub">
  <input type="button" value="divisão" id="divi">
  <input type="button" value="multiplicação" id="multip">
  <div class="resultado"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The event listeners are attached to each button individually using addEventListener.
Inside each event listener, the values of campo1 and campo2 are retrieved, and the corresponding calculation is performed.
The result is directly updated in the `.resultado` div by assigning the desired text to the innerHTML property.

```js
const campo1 = document.querySelector('#campo1');
const campo2 = document.querySelector('#campo2')
const resultado = document.querySelector('.resultado');

document.querySelector('#soma').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const num1 = Number(campo1.value);
    const num2 = Number(campo2.value);
    const somando = num1 + num2;
    resultado.innerHTML = `A soma foi ${somando}`;
});

document.querySelector('#sub').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const num1 = Number(campo1.value);
    const num2 = Number(campo2.value);
    const subtraindo = num1 - num2;
    resultado.innerHTML = `A subtração foi ${subtraindo}`;
});

document.querySelector('#divi').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const num1 = Number(campo1.value);
    const num2 = Number(campo2.value);
    const dividindo = num1 / num2;
    resultado.innerHTML = `A divisão foi ${dividindo}`;
});

document.querySelector('#multip').addEventListener('click', function () {
    const num1 = Number(campo1.value);
    const num2 = Number(campo2.value);
    const multiplicando = num1 * num2;
    resultado.innerHTML = `A multiplicação foi ${multiplicando}`;
});
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
    <input type="number" name="campo1" id="campo1">
    <input type="number" name="campo2" id="campo2">
    <input type="button" value="soma" id="soma">
    <input type="button" value="subtração" id="sub">
    <input type="button" value="divisão" id="divi">
    <input type="button" value="multiplicação" id="multip">
    <div class="resultado"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a function for each button, you can just get all `type=button` with [**querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), then loop thru each element and use [**addEventListener**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to each element.

Once an button is clicked you can do `console.log(op.id)` and it will print the id of the button that was clicked and thats how you will know which operation to do wich a `switch/case`

```js
const resultado = document.querySelector('.resultado');
const operations = document.querySelectorAll('[type=button]');
operations.forEach(op => {
  op.addEventListener('click', function() {
    const num1 = Number(document.querySelector('#campo1').value);
    const num2 = Number(document.querySelector('#campo2').value);
    switch (op.id) {
      case "soma":
        //console.log("soma")
        const somando = num1 + num2;
        resultado.innerHTML = `A soma foi ${somando}`;
        break;
      case "sub":
        //console.log("subtração")
        const subtraindo = num1 - num2;
        resultado.innerHTML = `A subtração foi ${subtraindo}`;
        break;
      case "multip":
        //console.log("multiplicação")
        const multiplicando = num1 * num2;
        resultado.innerHTML = `A multiplicação foi ${multiplicando}`;
        break;
      case "divi":
        //console.log("divisão")
        const dividindo = num1 / num2;
        resultado.innerHTML = `A divisão foi ${dividindo}`;
        break;

    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form action="" id="form">
  <input type="number" name="campo1" id="campo1">
  <input type="number" name="campo2" id="campo2">
  <input type="button" value="soma" id="soma">
  <input type="button" value="subtração" id="sub">
  <input type="button" value="divisão" id="divi">
  <input type="button" value="multiplicação" id="multip">
  <div class="resultado"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [submitter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent/submitter) to get the button that did the submit event.

And when working with forms, use the name attribute instead of the id attribute. Names do not have to be unique throughout the document and it is quite convenient when you know the context of the form to get the right input element.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let resultado = e.target.resultado;
  let campo1 = Number(e.target.campo1.value);
  let campo2 = Number(e.target.campo2.value);
  // switch based on the name of the clicked button
  switch(e.submitter.name){
    case 'soma':
      resultado.value = campo1 + campo2;
      break;
    case 'subtração':
      resultado.value = campo1 - campo2;
      break;
    case 'divisão':
      resultado.value = campo1 / campo2;
      break;
    case 'multiplicação':
      resultado.value = campo1 * campo2;
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="" name="form01">
  <input type="number" name="campo1">
  <input type="number" name="campo2">
  <button name="soma">soma</button>
  <button name="subtração">subtração</button>
  <button name="divisão">divisão</button>
  <button name="multiplicação">multiplicação</button>
  <br>
  <output name="resultado"></output>
</form>
```